Wanted to give superpowers to a kid with neurodivergence
I’m writing a story with the main character having the ability to hyperfocus on things. However, I would like to give the character the ability to transform. Let’s say, her hair could transform into a rope.
Anyways, my story is about the exchange of human knowledge through battles.
How to elaborate on the exchange of human knowledge part?

Remember that with great power comes great responsibility. Make sure that the neurodivergent person is able to handle the responsibility of that power.

Well, what if the hyper focus can make her feel more immersed in her academic pursuits?

I don't understand the question. Is the question asking whether it is allowed to give superpowers to neurodivergent child? AFAIK there is no law against that, at least not in Romania, but you may want to ask on Law SE to make sure. Remember to specify the jurisdiction. If this is not what the question is asking, then what is the question asking?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Any suggestions for this? Go for it, historically with superheroes & supervillains any power can be given to anyone. There is no set limits.


You can't ask brainstorming questions here. I'm surprised that you got two answers already.
If you want superpower ideas, go here: https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Superpower_Wiki

Questions here need to be phrased in a way that users can objectively rank answers as 'good' or 'bad'.  This site doesn't do well with 'what-if's.

This is quite a demanding scenario.  A power to transform hair into a rope, for example, implies something hair can't do, by the rules of our universe.
There's the loophole.  Hyper-focus allows Protagonist to see beyond this single four-dimensional slice of reality.  Our universe exists beside many other versions of the same cosmos, each with some significant quantum of difference from the next, but each similar in many regards to the next.
To understand this scenario, note that causality proceeds from the conscious mind both backward and forward in time.  In other words, we reject the myth of past causality, where a certain arrangement of vibrations after the Big Bang "really mattered" and the slightest perturbation of it means the Earth never happened.  Instead, we know what is happening right now is real, and any minor perturbation of current circumstances in the next universe could mean that the Big Bang was very different, or maybe there was some completely different beginning to the cosmos.  So long as no conscious observer was there, what really happened is just a matter of theory.
Protagonist has the ability to recall and understand the other universes near ours.  With a focus so calm it would not ruffle a feather of Maat, the Protagonist retains conscious awareness of events from and into the next Day of Ra across the abyss of Duat - and the next, and the next.  Note that various combinations of Kemetist, Christian, and Hindu concepts and terminology can be applied to good effect when speaking of "the next world", provided you don't insist on finding the perfect world just one single step away.
This gives Protagonist the ability to center her conscious awareness in another universe where the sequence of events is different, the rules of physics might be a little different, the pace of time might be different.  So she could, for example, see herself in a world along the Spiritual Future Dimension where the villain, having not been "saved", never existed at all, and is represented only as a little stuffed scarecrow someone left out to frighten credulous children.  There she could patiently braid her hair around it, and then come back, and as this world struggles to stay roughly consistent with the other reality, we see her hair "spontaneously", by some utterly implausible fluke of probability, turn into an attacking noose.
